# Unable to import smtplib in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>import smtplib
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, 
>  in <module> importemail.utils
>  File "email.py", line 3, 
>  in <module> from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
>  ImportError: cannot import name SMTP_SSL
```

Comment: Can you post some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: By any chance do you have a folder or file named email.py or email in your current directory , if so change the file or folder name and try importing smtplib

Comment: Thanks @Ram. I had several files named email in that directory.

Comment: Since smtplib.py has an import email.utils , it starts to search for utils in your local email file instead of /usr/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py .